# "NOT a feather file" when reading feather file from pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyarrow, feather

I'm new to this. Any ideas? Thank you somcuh!
[image]

Comment: The fact it says `'.feather'` does not mean the file is in actual `.feather` format. Make sure the file is exported correctly

Comment: Furthermore, if you believe it is a feather file, please post a small representative sample file (that fails) or provide more details about how you are creating the file.

Answer (score 0):

There was a [bug in Arrow 2.0](https://github.com/apache/arrow/pull/9128) that caused problems in reading compressed feather files written with Arrow 0.17; if you're using Arrow 2.0, it's possible that upgrading to 3.0 might fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I was using old Pandas (0.25) and old Pyarrow (0.17) versions. I updated these two packages to Pandas 1.3.5 and Pyarrow 12.0.1 and it fixed my problem.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35406181)

Comment: @MicheleLaFerla This may not have helped you but it helped me and hence I added this answer in case anyone was going through the same issue. Please add if you have a better answer. Thanks!